# Postfix Can Send But Cannot Receive Mail, Port 25 is Filtered

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I seem to have a problem with port 25 inbound connection. My ISP confirmed that port 25 is open. Yet, when I tested with nmap, I get the following results

[Testing nmap with public IP shows port 25 is filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Ney.jpg)

Testing port 25 using the local IP of the server shows that port 25 is open.
However, testing nmap using the public / external IP shows that port 25 is filtered.
I didn't include it in the picture, but testing with netstat also shows that Postfix (master.cf) is listening on that port.

The Postfix on my server can send mail and I have tested it a few times, it works without any problem.
But it cannot receive mail, and I strongly suspect it has something to do with the state of port 25 being filtered when accessing it from the external public IP. Yet my ISP insisted that port 25 is open. My ISP gave me this as a result of their check: `16 permit tcp any My.Public.IP.Address 0.0.0.3 eq smtp`

SMTP refers to port 25, and they permit any tcp traffic through that port, if I understand that correctly. But why is the port still being filtered when checked using the public IP?

What else can I do to narrow down the issue? Any leads would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, the network obstacle indeed exists with the ISP. The ports weren't forwarded properly.
Apparently the tech support people that I've dealt with with the support ticket system doesn't actually understand what I'm talking about.

So I've called the ISP and spoken to a tech support personnel who knows what he's doing. Issue was resolved in minutes.